# How to have a public and private branch with hidden files

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge

Alright, so I was following these directions:

https://24ways.org/2013/keeping-parts-of-your-codebase-private-on-github/

What I am looking for is a way to have branch A of a local repo track a public remote on Github and branch B of the same local repo track a private remote.

The private branch (B) would have a bunch of extra files in it that I want hidden from the public branch (A).

The article above seems to suggest that the best way to do this is to create a "dev" branch, let's call it C and then push the changes from the dev branch to both branch A and branch B. The problem is that if I delete files from A or C and then those changes get merged into B, those files will get deleted from B, but I want those files in the private branch!

How can I accomplish having a public branch and private branch and ensure that files don't get deleted from the private branch during merges?

*Perhaps the only way is to have a different .gitignore file in the separate branches?*

Comment: The article only seems to show setting up one local repo to point to a public and private GitHub repo.  Using gitignore sounds like a good start.

Comment: yeah I only want one local repo, but having tow branches in that repo, I think my use case is identical to the one in the article, but the article does not mention .gitignore so I cannot figure out how he solves the problem of deleted files